# Daw line between 2 points

Tags: java, android, graphics, draw

I  am trying to draw a line between 2 points. I can draw a line between 2 points like: A to B to C. But I want to draw lines between them like A to C or C to A.

Also I wanted to draw those lines on a image background. I have a background there, but when i draw a line with background my app is lagging.

Here's the code:

```
package com.example.grzegorz.kropy;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.graphics.drawable.*;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
public class PaintView extends View {

private Bitmap mBitmap;
private Canvas mCanvas; // holds the "draw" calls
private Path mPath; //Create an empty path
private Paint mPaint; // the style and color information about how to draw geometries, text and bitmaps.
private static final int TOUCH_TOLERANCE_DP = 24;
private static final int BACKGROUND =0xFFCC00 ;

private List<Point> mPoints = new ArrayList<Point>();
private int mLastPointIndex = 0;
private int mTouchTolerance;
private boolean isPathStarted = false;


public PaintView(Context context) {
    super(context);

    mCanvas = new Canvas();
    mPath = new Path();
    mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mPaint.setDither(true);
    mPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(12);
    mTouchTolerance = dp2px(TOUCH_TOLERANCE_DP);

    // TODO just test points
    Point p1 = new Point(20, 20);
    Point p2 = new Point(100, 100);
    Point p3 = new Point(200, 250);
    Point p4 = new Point(280, 400);
    Point p5 = new Point(350, 600);
    Point p6 = new Point(400, 500);
    Point p7 = new Point(450, 500);
    mPoints.add(p1);
    mPoints.add(p2);
    mPoints.add(p3);
    mPoints.add(p4);
    mPoints.add(p5);
    mPoints.add(p6);
    mPoints.add(p7);
}

public PaintView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.polacz);
    mCanvas = new Canvas();
    mPath = new Path();
    mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mPaint.setDither(true);
    mPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(12);
    mTouchTolerance = dp2px(TOUCH_TOLERANCE_DP);

    // TODO just test points
    Point p1 = new Point(20, 20);
    Point p2 = new Point(100, 100);
    Point p3 = new Point(200, 250);
    Point p4 = new Point(280, 400);
    Point p5 = new Point(350, 600);
    Point p6 = new Point(400, 500);
    Point p7 = new Point(450, 500);
    mPoints.add(p1);
    mPoints.add(p2);
    mPoints.add(p3);
    mPoints.add(p4);
    mPoints.add(p5);
    mPoints.add(p6);
    mPoints.add(p7);
}

public PaintView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    mCanvas = new Canvas();
    mPath = new Path();
    mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mPaint.setDither(true);
    mPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(12);
    mTouchTolerance = dp2px(TOUCH_TOLERANCE_DP);

}

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int width, int height, int oldWidth, int oldHeight) {
    super.onSizeChanged(width, height, oldWidth, oldHeight);
    clear();
}
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    //canvas.drawColor(BACKGROUND);

    Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.polacz);
    d.setBounds(canvas.getClipBounds());
    d.draw(canvas);
 //   mCustomImage.setBounds(canvas.getClipBounds());
 //   mCustomImage.draw(canvas);
    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, null);
    //   canvas.drawBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),   R.drawable.polacz1), 0, 0, null);
    canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);

    // TODO remove if you dont want points to be drawn
    for (Point point : mPoints) {
        canvas.drawPoint(point.x, point.y, mPaint);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX();
    float y = event.getY();

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            touch_start(x, y);
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            touch_move(x, y);
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            touch_up(x, y);
            invalidate();
            break;
    }
    return true;
}

private void touch_start(float x, float y) {

    if (checkPoint(x, y, mLastPointIndex)) {
        mPath.reset();
        // user starts from given point so path can beis started
        isPathStarted = true;
    } else {
        // user starts move from point which doen's belongs to mPinst list
        isPathStarted = false;
    }

}
private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
// draw line with finger move
    if (isPathStarted) {
        mPath.reset();
        Point p = mPoints.get(mLastPointIndex);
        mPath.moveTo(p.x, p.y);
        if (checkPoint(x, y, mLastPointIndex + 1)) {
            p = mPoints.get(mLastPointIndex + 1);
            mPath.lineTo(p.x, p.y);
            mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
            mPath.reset();
            ++mLastPointIndex;
        } else {
           mPath.lineTo(x, y);
       }
    }
}

/**
 * Draws line.
 */
private void touch_up(float x, float y) {
    mPath.reset();
    if (checkPoint(x, y, mLastPointIndex + 1) && isPathStarted) {
        // move finished at valid point so draw whole line

        // start point
        Point p = mPoints.get(mLastPointIndex);
        mPath.moveTo(p.x, p.y);
        // end point
        p = mPoints.get(mLastPointIndex + 1);
        mPath.lineTo(p.x, p.y);
        mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
        mPath.reset();
        // increment point index
        ++mLastPointIndex;
        isPathStarted = false;
    }

}

/**
 * Sets paint
 *
 * @param paint
 */
public void setPaint(Paint paint) {
    this.mPaint = paint;
}

/**
 * Returns image as bitmap
 *
 * @return
 */
public Bitmap getBitmap() {
    return mBitmap;
}

/**
 * Clears canvas
 */
public void clear() {
    mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(getWidth(), getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    mBitmap.eraseColor(BACKGROUND);
    mCanvas.setBitmap(mBitmap);
    invalidate();
}

/**
 * Checks if user touch point with some tolerance
 */
private boolean checkPoint(float x, float y, int pointIndex) {
    if (pointIndex == mPoints.size()) {
        // out of bounds
        return false;
    }
    Point point = mPoints.get(pointIndex);
    //EDIT changed point.y to poin.x in the first if statement
    if (x > (point.x - mTouchTolerance) && x < (point.x + mTouchTolerance)) {
        if (y > (point.y - mTouchTolerance) && y < (point.y + mTouchTolerance)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public List<Point> getPoints() {
    return mPoints;
}

public void setPoints(List<Point> points) {
    this.mPoints = points;
}

private int dp2px(int dp) {
    Resources r = getContext().getResources();
    float px = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dp, r.getDisplayMetrics());
    return (int) px;
}
}
```

XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false">
<com.example.grzegorz.kropy.PaintView
android:layout_width="670dp"
android:layout_height="820dp"
 />

<!--<Button-->
    <!--android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
    <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
    <!--android:text="graj"-->
    <!--android:id="@+id/button"-->
    <!--android:layout_alignParentTop="true"-->
    <!--android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"-->
    <!--android:onClick="gra"-->
    <!--android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />-->
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: So, does this mean you cannot draw lines from C to A and A to C, or only that it seems too slow? Can you provide more information on the use case? From the code it seems that at the start the points are drawn but the lines are only drawn if the user draws them with their finger (touch input)? Is this correct?

Comment: 7 points are drawn on the beginning there. I can draw a line between them with my finger. Lines can be drawn only sequentially. p1 to p2, p2 to p3, p3 to p4... I wanted to draw it freely. About the speed of drawing, my app is lagging when i add image as background. Without the background it works smoothly.

Answer (score 1):

### Try solution works for me

```html
public class DrawView extends View {
      Paint paint = new Paint();
      View startView1;
      View endView1; 
      int myToken;
      float sX,sY,eX,eY;
      public DrawView(Context context,View startView ,View endView) {
       super(context); 
       paint.reset();
       myToken=token;
       paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
       this.startView1 = startView;
       this.endView1 = endView;
     
      }
    
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    
       paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
       canvas.drawLine(startView1.getX()+startView1.getWidth() / 2.F,    startView1.getY()+startView1.getHeight()/ 2.F, endView1.getX()+endView1.getWidth() / 2.F, endView1.getY()+endView1.getHeight() / 2.F, paint);
       
      }
    
     }
    
    
    and call this DrawView class as :
    
    Button btn1=(Button) findViewById(id1);
             Button btn2=(Button) findViewById(id2);
             DrawView drawView = new DrawView(RoasterScreen.this,btn1,btn2);
rootLayout.addView(drawView);
```

Comment: @RaviMakvana, What modifications you did please ?

Comment: i forgot it, but i know that i removed error which is occurred while  implementing code.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class DrawingPanel extends View implements OnTouchListener {

private Canvas mCanvas;
private Path mPath;
private Paint mPaint, mBitmapPaint;
private ArrayList<PathPoints> paths = new ArrayList<PathPoints>();
private ArrayList<PathPoints> undonePaths = new ArrayList<PathPoints>();
private Bitmap mBitmap;
private int color;
public int SSL = Color.WHITE;
private int x, y;
private int strockWidth = 3;

private String textToDraw = null;
public static boolean isTextModeOn = false;


//public static boolean flag = true;
//public static int angle = 0;

public DrawingPanel(Context context, int color, Bitmap bitmap) {
    super(context);
    this.color = color;
    System.out.println("---> Drawing pannel Construction <--- ");
    setFocusable(true);
    setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

    this.setOnTouchListener(this);

    mBitmap = bitmap;
    mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
    mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mPaint.setDither(true);
    mPaint.setColor(color);
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(strockWidth);
    mPaint.setTextSize(30);

    mPath = new Path();
    paths.add(new PathPoints(mPath, color,strockWidth, false));
    mCanvas = new Canvas();
}

public void colorChanged(int color) {
    this.color = color;
    mPaint.setColor(color);
    //invalidate();
}

public void changeWidthOfStrock(int strockWidth) {
    this.strockWidth = strockWidth;
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(strockWidth);
    //invalidate();

}



@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    // mBitmap = AddReportItemActivity.mPhoto;
    //mBitmap = getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable("Bitmap");
    System.out.println("mBitmap"+mBitmap);
    if(mBitmap != null) {
        float xscale = (float) w / (float) mBitmap.getWidth();
        float yscale = (float) h / (float) mBitmap.getHeight();
        if (xscale > yscale) // make sure both dimensions fit (use the
            xscale = yscale;
        float newx = (float) w * xscale;
        float newy = (float) h * xscale; // use the same scale for both
                                        // dimensions
    }
    // if you want it centered on the display (black borders)
    mBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(mBitmap, this.getWidth(),this.getHeight(), true);
    // mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
    for (PathPoints p : paths) {
        mPaint.setColor(p.getColor());
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(p.getStrockWidth());
        if (p.isTextToDraw()) {
            //canvas.drawText(p.textToDraw, p.x, p.y, mPaint);
        } else {
            canvas.drawPath(p.getPath(), mPaint);
        }
    }
    mPaint.setColor(SSL);
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(strockWidth);
    canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
}

private float mX, mY;
private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 0;

private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
    mPath.reset();
    mPath.moveTo(x, y);
    mX = x;
    mY = y;
}

private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
    float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
    float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
    if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
        mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX) / 2, (y + mY) / 2);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
    }
}

private void touch_up() {
    mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
    // commit the path to our offscreen
    mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
    // kill this so we don't double draw
    //mPath = new Path();
    paths.add(new PathPoints(mPath, SSL,strockWidth ,false));
    mPath = new Path();

}

private void drawText(int x, int y) {
    //Log.v(TAG, "Here");
    //Log.v(TAG, "X " + x + " Y " + y);
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    paths.add(new PathPoints(color, textToDraw, true, x, y));
    // mCanvas.drawText(textToDraw, x, y, mPaint);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX();
    float y = event.getY();

    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        if (!isTextModeOn) {
            touch_start(x, y);
            invalidate();
        }
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        if (!isTextModeOn) {
            touch_move(x, y);
            invalidate();
        }
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        if (isTextModeOn) {
            drawText((int) x, (int) y);
            invalidate();
        } else {
            touch_up();
            invalidate();
        }
        break;
    }
    return true;
}

public void onClickUndo() {
    if (paths.size() > 0) {
        undonePaths.add(paths.remove(paths.size() - 1));
        invalidate();
    } else {

    }
    // toast the user
}

public void onClickRedo() {
    if (undonePaths.size() > 0) {
        paths.add(undonePaths.remove(undonePaths.size() - 1));
        invalidate();
    } else {

    }
    // toast the user
}


class PathPoints {
    private Path path;
    // private Paint mPaint;
    private int color;
    private int strockW;
    private String textToDraw;
    private boolean isTextToDraw;
    private int x, y;

    public PathPoints(Path path, int color,int strockWidth ,boolean isTextToDraw) {
        this.path = path;
        this.color = color;
        this.strockW = strockWidth;
        this.isTextToDraw = isTextToDraw;
    }

    public PathPoints(int color, String textToDraw, boolean isTextToDraw,int x, int y) {
        this.color = color;
        this.textToDraw = textToDraw;
        this.isTextToDraw = isTextToDraw;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public Path getPath() {
        return path;
    }

    public void setPath(Path path) {
        this.path = path;
    }

    /*
     * private Paint getPaint() { mPaint = new Paint();
     * mPaint.setAntiAlias(true); mPaint.setColor(color);
     * mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
     * mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
     * mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND); mPaint.setStrokeWidth(6);
     * return mPaint; }
     */

    public int getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(int color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public int getStrockWidth() {
        return strockW;
    }

    public void setStrokWidth(int color) {
        this.strockW = color;
    }

    public String getTextToDraw() {
        return textToDraw;
    }

    public void setTextToDraw(String textToDraw) {
        this.textToDraw = textToDraw;
    }

    public boolean isTextToDraw() {
        return isTextToDraw;
    }

    public void setTextToDraw(boolean isTextToDraw) {
        this.isTextToDraw = isTextToDraw;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

}
```

}

---

Add this view into your layout

DrawingPanel drawingPanel = new DrawingPanel(getApplicationContext(), color, bitmap);
        rl_layout.addView(drawingPanel);

Comment: Where should i add this view to my layout? I add new java class with DrawingPanel.

Comment: In main layout <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false">
<com.example.grzegorz.kropy.PaintView
android:layout_width="670dp"
android:layout_height="820dp"
 />